# Check for values other than '1' in excel column and display MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have to regularly sort excel spreadsheets containing several hundred rows of invoice data. I have a macro to format the data the way I need it. However one thing I need to do is check the quantity column for any amounts greater or less than '1' and display a MsgBox with two options if it finds a value <> than 1.

What I would like to do is have some vba code that checks all cells from column L2 down to the end of the data (until it finds a blank cell). Then if it finds a value that does not = 1, (either a - or + value) display a MsgBox with the message "Quantity Errors Found. Continue "Yes" "No". If  "Yes" is selected the macro is allowed to continue to format the spreadsheet as normal. If "No" is selected the macro is terminated to allow the error to be fixed.

The reason I need the Yes/No option is that there are a few instances where the differing quantities can be left. So when I run the macro I am able to exit and check if the values can be left and run again, this time selecting 'Yes' and continuing.

Appreciate anyone who can help and provide some code to do this.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: Thank you, however John answered my question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let the spreadsheet do some of the work. In an available cell enter the formula

```
=COUNTIF(L2:L1000,1) <>COUNTA(L2:L1000)
```

Where the range is large enough to include all of the data. This formula will return true if there is a nonblank cell whose value differs from 1. Your code could just check the value of this cell.

On the other hand, you might want to loop if e.g. you want to highlight the offending cell. You can use a while loop to step through the cells in column L starting at L2 and stopping when you encounter a blank cell. For each such cell, check if its value is <> 1. If it isn't 1 - use msgbox to get input from the user. For most beginning VBA programmers, it is this last step which would cause the most problem since most beginners tend to use msgbox exclusively as a sub.

The following sub illustrates how to use msgbox as a function (rather than as a sub):

```
Sub EarlyStop()
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    answer = MsgBox("Error found, continue?", vbYesNo)
    If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "Sub continuing normally"
End Sub
```

Note the parenthesis around the arguments in the first msgbox but not around the second -- this is one of the quirks of VBA. If you use msgbox as a function you need to use parenthesis, but not when you use it as a sub.

When you run this sub, if you select No in the first msgbox then nothing else happens since the sub is over. If you select Yes then you see a second msgbox to illustrate how execution continued normally. In your code, you should have the declaration at the top of your sub and the two lines starting with "answer" to be conditionally executed if the value is <> 1

Comment: Thanks John, Using a combination  of the cell formula and the code you suggested for the msgbox, I have managed to do exactly what I wanted.